# I need to put a small 20x20 image right next to a label HTML/CSS the image keeps going underneath it. Should I use a div?

Tags: html, css, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUrmr.png) HTML

```
 <div id="rectangle">
  <img src='./assets/images/logo.png'>
  <label id="in-out">Clock In / Out</label>
  <label id="time-label">Time:</label>
  <label id="timenum">1:23 PM</label>
  <label id="employeepin">Employee PIN</label>
  <input id="pinbox" type="text" name="pin">
  <button id="enter" type="button">Enter</button>


  <img id="chevron" src="./assets/images/chevron-right.png">
  <label id="username">Or, Log In with Username and Password. </label>


</div>
```

CSS for the username label and the image.

```
#username {
  height: 48px;
  width: 328px;
  margin-left: 106px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-top: 1px;

}
#chevron {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 380px;
  margin-right: 106px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

I need for it to say "Or login with your username and password." with the 20px x 20px image to the right of the statement. thanks

Comment: if the image is not part of the content it should be included as a background of the label on `center right` position

Comment: omg, why not to learn the basics first? Whatever. Put in a container and use "float", or "display:inline-block", or "flexbox", or "position:absolute"

Comment: ::before, ::after is another implementation))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```css
   #username {
     height: 48px;
     width: 328px;
     margin-left: 106px;
     margin-right: 1px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
    }
    #chevron {
     height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: 14px;
     }
```

```html
    
<label id="username">Or, Log In with Username and Password. <img id="chevron" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/search.png"></label>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried it out and posted an image of what it is doing, can you please take a look

Comment: @ahakjsdh Could you post the live URL?

Answer (score 0):

How about like this

```
<div class="advice">
  <label id="username">Or, Log In with Username and Password.</label>
  <img id="chevron" src="./assets/images/chevron-right.png">
</div>

.advice {
  "margin-top: 1px; 
}
#username {
  height: 48px;
  width: 328px;
  margin-left: 106px;
}

#chevron {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 106px;
}
```